# ng-class not working even when variable is toggled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have this broadcast receiver which receives info when data= false if should toggle a class:

```
$rootScope.$on('toggleRangeMode:broadcast', function (event, data) {
    $scope.isRangeMode = data;
    console.log("$scope.isRangeMode", $scope.isRangeMode) // I have this console log and even when the variable is FALSE it does not work   
});
```

This is how my html looks:

```
 <a class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-warning': isRangeMode, 'btn-white': !isRangeMode}"></a>
```

Comment: is `$scope.isRangeMod` bool value or string

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

I guess you are unable to observe the change in style since your hyperlink doesn't contains any text

Hyperlink class is changing whenever the `isRangeMode` value changes.

I've used $timeout for the demonstration purpose.

## demo

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout'];

function MyController($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $rootScope.$on('toggleRangeMode:broadcast', function(event, data) {
    $scope.isRangeMode = data;
    console.log("$scope.isRangeMode", $scope.isRangeMode);
    // I have this console log and even when the variable is FALSE it does not work   
  });

  $rootScope.$emit('toggleRangeMode:broadcast', true);
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('toggleRangeMode:broadcast', false);
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <a class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-warning': isRangeMode, 'btn-white': !isRangeMode}">link</a> {{isRangeMode}} {{ isRangeMode?'btn-warning':'btn-white'}}
</div>
```